# android-Java- converting a WeakReference<Bitmap> to a normal Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, weak-references

Ive been working on an app for a while that uses lots of Bitmaps and Ive gotten it to the point where its working really well on most devices that Ive tested it on except for a newer droid bionic that runs 2.3.4

I get an out of memory error and I can see the heap growing in the logcat too. So far Ive tried re-sizing the bitmaps with different techniques which works great for every other device except the new droid bionic which is weird being that you would think a newer phone would handle vm better.

Ive looked at some other threads on here that talk about using various methods but the one Im interested in using involves using WeakReferenced to store images as. This is great but how can I convert the weakreference back to a normal bitmap to use on a canvas.

EDIT: heres a recent stack trace dumparoo :p

```
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: go
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.init(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:79)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.<init>(SocketInputBuffer.java:93)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:83)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:170)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:106)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:129)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:363)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at graffit.data.ImageGrabber.imagegetter(ImageGrabber.java:164)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at graffit.data.ImageGrabber.traverseIDS(ImageGrabber.java:118)
09-30 12:33:09.231  2867  2922 E AndroidRuntime:    at graffit.data.ImageGrabber$getMarkImageThread.run(ImageGrabber.java:238)
09-30 12:33:09.239   480   750 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity graffit.main/.GraffView
09-30 12:33:09.669   480   873 I ActivityManager: Process graffit.main (pid 2867) has died.
09-30 12:33:09.677   480   590 I WindowManager: WINDOW DIED Window{407c4100 graffit.main/graffit.main.GraffView paused=true}
09-30 12:33:09.677   480   590 I WindowManager: WINDOW DIED Window{408044e0 Toast paused=false}
09-30 12:33:09.684   480   759 I WindowManager: Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you making http calls in your code using the Apache DefaultHttpClient?

I've recently discovered a problem specific to the Droid Bionic which causes it to use a lot more VM memory than other Android devices while downloading files using the HttpClient. This may be the true cause of your memory leaks if your are not experiencing an OutOfMemoryError on other devices.

Do you have any stack traces that indicate an OutOfMemoryError during a http call?

I believe the work-around code starting at line 64 in the following source maybe missing on the Droid Bionic build:

http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#CskViEIa27Y/src/org/apache/http/impl/io/SocketInputBuffer.java&q=package:android.git.kernel.org%20file:org/apache/http/impl/io/SocketInputBuffer.java&l=1

You can fix this by using HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192) when you create your http client.

Comment: Yeah thats the exact problem Im having dude.  heres a stack trace of stuff added to my question up above.

Comment: HttpPost post = new HttpPost(strUrl);
     post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp1));
     try{System.gc();
     
     response = client.execute(post);           So this response = client.execute(post); is what the logcat points at as the culprit. How would I use the httpconnectionsparams with that.

Comment: AH HA LOL.....I got man.....I wrote it up like this and it worked like magic   post = new HttpPost(strUrl);
     params = post.getParams();
     post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp1));
     try{System.gc();
     HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params, 8192);
     response = client.execute(post);

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Just a note, you should never have to do System.gc(). Even when juggling lots of bitmaps. If you find that System.gc() fixes some OutOfMemoryError, then the truth of the matter is that it has merely delayed an OutOfMemoryError. Hunt for the memory leak instead (easier said than done, I know).

Comment: Yeah Ive read that plenty of times how ever the application Im working on downloads lots and lots and lots of bitmaps from activity to acitivity. Im kind of relying on it now for a temp fix and Ive actually removed it from most places without even noticing a difference on the used heap.

Comment: This is a really great answer. Bionic users were seeing tons of force closes for my app, some relating to OutOfMemoryErrors but also a ton of seemingly-unrelated NullPointerExceptions relating to some built-in Bionic XML layouts. Plugging this huge memory leak seems to have fixed the root cause of all these issues! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[WeakReference.get()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#get%28%29)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply :) but how can I use that to convert the weakreferenced bitmap to a normal bitmap.

Comment: If you have a `WeakReference<Bitmap>`, calling `get()` on it will return a `Bitmap` (or `null` if the reference has been cleared).

Comment: Hey just so you know that use of WeakReference for my bitmaps was to good lol.....garbage collection was cleaning them up to fast for use and everything was blank so I had to try and just null everything with a house cleaning method I call from the instantiated class I use.

Comment: Perhaps what you really wanted was a `SoftReference<Bitmap>`? Weak references may be cleared as soon as there are no strong references to them anywhere. Soft references will be held even after there are no strong references but may be cleared in response to memory demand.

Comment: Yeah I thought about using that but I think Nilz solution fixed my problem. Im pretty sure now that it was the http process that was running out of space to operate. Im thinking that the 4g download speed was to much for the gc to clean up at a good pace. But thanks so much for the help using the weak/soft references. Ill be sure to use them in the future when I think they are needed.